# how to make imageView take match parent of relativelayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, gif, android-relativelayout

i'm trying to make `ImageView` take **match_parent** of `RelativeLayout` 
like this picture :

[image]

when i run my app `ImageView` looks like that :

[image]

this my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linealL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/khdar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGriviewBorder"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:text="GIF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGriviewBorder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dev"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/imageSelectTo"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `layout_width` of ImageView to `match_parent` and add one new attribute to it: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fit the `ImageView`  `width` then You have to ignore `height`. And by default will not strech for you to keep aspect ratio, so you need to add another attributes for adjust view bounds. So lastly you will have your code chages as follows for an `ImageView`:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

The adjust View bounds will adjust to a particular height while keeping the aspect ratio.

**More**
Also to avoid future mistakes again in your code you have nested two `RelativeLayout`'s which I guess is due backgrounds. If there is no need for that If do not care about space. The inner `RelativeLayout` View `height` and `width` should be set to `match_parent`!. **Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 2):

Your `ImageView`'s `layout_width` and `layout_height` are set to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.